# cPanel Error: Domain is owned by another user

Tags: cpanel

When trying to create an addon domain or parked domain in cPanel I get the following error:

```
[domain name] is owned by another user.
```

The domain is not being listed as an addon domain or a parked domain.

And idea what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check to see if the domain or subdomain is already owned by another user.

This includes checking DNS. WHM won't let you park a domain if there are any existing DNS records for that domain. So look through your DNS zones as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having root access try checking any instances of the domain name

> grep domain.com /etc/userdomains

For checking the dns zones. Try these

> Home »DNS Functions »Edit DNS Zone

If there any instances of the domain's dns, You need to delete that to before adding the domain as addon or park again.